# How to remove index number from laravel eloquent unique

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using a query that returns value perfectly but it adds key number to the collection. How can I remove the index number?

Here is the retrieved data

```
{
"data": {
    "0": {
        "id": 135,
        "conversation_id": 11,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 54,
            "userName": "Sadek",
            "profilePic": "Nir7zgorNT2dmwcXJdhNK3ZmPAltmkEnj0SXDCDC.png",
            "firstName": "Sadek",
            "lastName": "Hossain"
        },
        "msg": "hello guys how are you",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 16:56:41",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 16:56:41"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 133,
        "conversation_id": 13,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 55,
            "userName": "buyer",
            "profilePic": "pRBDBFJW55baSnF560Ajid8jTgPo5kmg4i5LMhPG.jpeg",
            "firstName": "Matti",
            "lastName": "Rames"
        },
        "msg": "second message 2 to user second",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14"
    }
}
```

}

But I want to return results like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 133,
        "conversation_id": 13,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 55,
            "userName": "buyer",
            "profilePic": "pRBDBFJW55baSnF560Ajid8jTgPo5kmg4i5LMhPG.jpeg",
            "firstName": "Matti",
            "lastName": "Rames"
        },
        "msg": "second message 2 to user second",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 15:43:14"
    },
    {
        "id": 135,
        "conversation_id": 11,
        "last_sender": null,
        "last_reciever": {
            "id": 54,
            "userName": "Sadek",
            "profilePic": "Nir7zgorNT2dmwcXJdhNK3ZmPAltmkEnj0SXDCDC.png",
            "firstName": "Sadek",
            "lastName": "Hossain"
        },
        "msg": "hello guys how are you",
        "attachment": null,
        "deleted": 0,
        "seen": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-17 16:56:41",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-17 16:56:41"
    }
]
```

}

My query is (last few parts that I think is important)

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
->get()
->unique('conversation_id');
```

Please tell me how can I remove "0" and "2" from this collection.

Comment: try to use `$collection->toArray()` !!

Comment: Nope doesn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it manually

```
   $users=\App\User::get()->toArray(); // your query here 
   $data['data']=[];
   foreach($users as $user ){ 
         $data['data'][]=$user; 
    }
   $k=json_encode($data); dd($k);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: try    $data=json_encode($your_array); and see if it helps

Comment: No :( it only encodes. I want to remove these "0" and "2" outer array

Comment: $users=\App\User::get()->toArray(); // your query here
     $data['data']=[];
     foreach($users as $user ){
         $data['data'][]=$user;

     }
        $k=json_encode($data);
        dd($k);

Comment: Yes almost there but it adds extra 'data' outside when I return using `return response()->json([
                'data' =>$data
              ],200);`

Comment: Thank you. Finally did it changing few things :) 

`foreach($leftMsg as $l )
              { 
                $data[]=$l; 
              } `

please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you for helping!

Comment: added in answer :-)

Comment: just add ->values();

Answer (score 17):

In order to get a collection without a index you have to add the "values" method

```
$collection->unique('id')->values();
```