# Laravel use toArray to add object to array and remove key

Tags: php, laravel

```
$message = Message::where('agent_id', $agent->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

I used `unique()` on collection and now I got this result:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "post_id": 3,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "hello",
        "status": 0
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 4,
        "post_id": 5,
        "agent_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "message": "hi hello",
        "status": 0
    }
}
```

But I want to remove `key` index, I mean 0 and 3, desire output is:

```
[
    {
          "id": 1,
          "post_id": 3,
          "agent_id": 1,
          "user_id": 1,
          "message": "hello",
          "status": 0
    },
    {
          "id": 4,
          "post_id": 5,
          "agent_id": 1,
          "user_id": 2,
          "message": "hi hello",
          "status": 0
    }
]
```

I tried:

```
$message->unique('user_id')->toArray();
```

But not working. any idea?

I using Laravel.

Comment: Why you need to remove `key` index ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut Because at front (React) it give me error after I made it `unique` => `TypeError: items.map is not a function`

Comment: Try using group by `groupBy('user_id')`

Comment: The duplicate seems to have a better answer than the accepted one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795617/how-to-remove-index-number-from-laravel-eloquent-unique (not sure why it hasn't changed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `values` method of the Collection, similar to `array_values`:

```
$new = $message->values();
```

*Assuming `$message` is the Collection holding the result of the `unique` call.*

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `values`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-values)

Comment: What `values()` will do ? here. it just resets keys.

Comment: @NikleshRaut yes which will make the returned json not have any defined keys and be a json array ... the 0-indexed array will be an array in json not an object

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by `groupBy('user_id')`

```
$message = Message::where('agent_id', $agent->id)
           ->groupBy('user_id')
           ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
           ->get();
```

Comment: Good idea, it seems this clear than that approach, but there is a little problem with this. the reason that I used `unique` with `orderBy` was, keep last item, but in your solution, it keep first item as unique.

Comment: @tourtravel: you can change orderby from `desc` to `asc`

Comment: I did, but nothing different, it just reverse data order.